# Custom is_sorted function template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write my own is_sorted function template implementation instead of using std::is_sorted. Could you give me any idea about how to do it?
I want to use it only for arrays. So I want to make declaration like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
bool is_sorted (const T (&array)[N]); and 

bool operator>(const A &, const A &); is declared.
```

Answer (score 4):

The obvious way would be to compare each item to the one after it, and see if it's <= to that one.

You probably don't want to do that directly though. First of all, for sorting, the client is typically only required to ensure that `a < b` is defined, so you want to use `<` instead of `<=`. Second, you want to allow (but not require) the user to pass a comparator of their own, in case `<` isn't defined directly for some type or the desired sort uses a different criteria than `<` defines.

As such, you probably want to define two versions of `is_sorted`, one using `<` directly, the other using a comparator passed by the user.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

template <class InIt>
bool is_sorted(InIt b, InIt e) {
    if (b == e)           // No items -- sorted by definition
        return true;

    typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type first = *b;
    ++b;
    while (b != e) {    // skip if e-b == 1 (single item is sorted)
        if (*b < first)
            return false;
        first = *b;
        ++b;
    }
    return true;
}

template <class InIt, class Cmp>
bool is_sorted(InIt b, InIt e, Cmp cmp) { 
    if (b == e)
        return true;

    typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type first = *b;
    ++b;
    while (b != e) {    // skip if e-b == 1 (single item is sorte)
        if (cmp(*b, first))
            return false;
        first = *b;
        ++b;
    }
    return true;
}
```

To keep myself honest, a bit of test code, with sorted, unsorted, identical, and reversed elements, using `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::array`, and a built-in array:

```
#ifdef TEST
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> sorted{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 100};
    std::deque<int> unsorted{1, 5, 2, 7, 4};
    std::array<int, 7> ident = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3};
    int rev[] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    if (!is_sorted(std::begin(sorted), std::end(sorted)))
        std::cout << "Sorted array detected as un-sorted\n";
    if (is_sorted(std::begin(unsorted), std::end(unsorted)))
        std::cout << "Un-sorted array detected as sorted\n";
    if (!is_sorted(std::begin(ident), std::end(ident)))
        std::cout << "sorted array with duplicated detected as un-sorted\n";
    if (!is_sorted(std::begin(rev), std::end(rev), std::greater<int>()))
        std::cout << "Reverse sorted array detected as un-sorted\n";
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

This works fine for me with gcc 4.7.2. The `is_sorted` code seems to work fine with VC++ 2012 as well (though the test code requires some minor modifications, e.g., to eliminate use of uniform initialization, which it doesn't support yet).

Edit: if you don't mind a slightly tighter requirement on the iterators (forward iterators instead of input iterators), you can make the code simpler and often more efficient. For example, the code can be reduced to something like this:

```
template <class FwdIt>
bool is_sorted(FwdIt b, FwdIt e) {
    if (b == e)           // No items -- sorted by definition
        return true;

    for (FwdIt first = b; ++b != e; first = b) 
        if (*b < *first)
            return false;    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You make a copy of every item in the container as you walk...?? Seems like a huge performance drain to me (when non-trivial types are contained).

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Could be. It's a tradeoff between that and what you require of the iterator -- if you don't mind requiring random-access iterators, you can eliminate the copy pretty easily. If you want to support input iterators, you have little choice but to make a copy.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Why is that? [The standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) seems to only require forward iterators.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Input iterators are more restricted that forward iterators. With forward iterators, I believe you can eliminate the copy as well, though it's (marginally) less trivial than with random access iterators.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Well, just copy the iterator instead of the value, like the linked implementation does, no need for random access iterators. But you're right in that even that won't work with input iterators (the multiple deref is the problem, I think). Maybe tag dispatching based on the iterator category might be a good idea. Ok, it's a simplified example here, but just copying a value of an unknown (and possibly huge) type when unneccessary is really a no-go.

Comment: @ChristianRau: For those who care about it, I've added code for forward iterators. I'd expect `std::is_sorted` uses tag dispatch, but don't see much point in that work for throwaway code like this.

Comment: The official STL uses forward iterators for its `is_sorted`, not input iterators, so I don't know why you would write slower code (potentially *much* slower) just so that you can work with input iterators. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_sorted/

Comment: @StilesCrisis: I looked at things from the other direction: the standard library already provides a version that supports all *other* iterator categories, so the only possibility that seemed interesting at all was to support the one category it doesn't: input iterators.

Comment: Or maybe he has non-standard container and non-standard iterators and wants to know how to check their sorted-ness? This seems much more plausible to me... input iterators are more of a curiosity than anything else IMO. But I've seen lots of codebases that have custom containers.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: I suppose that could be, and if so, he probably wants to use the last piece of code in the answer, that's written for forward iterators. Better still, support a standard iterator interface -- about all you need for forward iterators is `begin()`, `end()`, and `++`.

Comment: Personally I agree about trying to mesh with the standard, but you'd be surprised and shocked at how many people I've met who not only don't care about that, they actually look down on it. Like, "the standard way is inefficient! don't bother spending any time on it! just roll your own and it'll be twice as good." Unfortunately, old versions of Dev Studio and their STL implementation (especially in Debug) have permanently left an impression on these devs. STL will forever be tainted as inefficient in their minds.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure each element in the container is `<=` the next element.

If you only have a `<` comparator (like most STL algorithms), make sure there are no elements in the container where the given element is `<` the previous element.